# better way to get the sum of a data.frame column in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

To put the `sum` of a `data.frame` column in a variable I did that:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame("x" = c(1,2,3), "y" = c("a","b","c"))
way01 <- data %>% filter(y == "d") %>% summarise(total = sum(x)) %>% .$total
way02 <- data %>% filter(y == "d") %>% .$x %>% sum
```

I feel it's clumsy to do `summarise(total = sum(x)) %>% .$total` or `%>% .$x %>% sum`. There is a more elegant way to do that?

I would like something like `%>% sum(.$x)`, but it doesn't work.

PS: it's proposital to use `"d"` as filter, to handler a case where `numeric(0)` is no problem.

Comment: If you are looking for a compact option, then `base R`  `with(data, sum(x[y=="d"]))`

Comment: @akrun tks. But it's a toy code for a bigger example with `dplyr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `%$%` instead of `%>%` to have direct access to columns:

```
> data %>% filter(y == "d") %$% sum(x)
[1] 0
```

Comment: or `data %$% sum(x[y == "d"])` maybe? :D

Answer (score 3):

You might be after:

```
way03 <- data %>% filter(y == "d") %>% { sum(.$x) }
```

The use of `{ }` is explained in:

```
?magrittr::`%>%`
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's used with a summary, you can always trick R and use dirty hacks:

```
data %>% summarise(total = sum(x[y == "d"])) %>% first()
```

or even

```
data %>% summarise(sum(x[y == "d"])) %>% first()
```

which returns:

```
[1] 0
```

Again, this is equivalent to `last()`, `nth(n=1)` and `nth(n=-1)` for this scenario.